# Linux terminal file opening

Tags: c, linux, file, terminal

This is some code that I wrote but I am confused to how to run it with linux terminal.
I tried writing like this:
asdasd:~/folder/file>./main.c file.txt but I just keep getting permission denied.
Do I need some other program to run this with? I hope I gave enough information to get some kind of feedback

(file.txt is the file I am trying to start the program with)

```
...........
void fileReader(int number, char *vector[])
{
    if(number!= 2)
    {
        printf("File: %s filename\n", vector[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(vector[1], "r");
    if(file == 0)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }
..........
........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compile the program.

You do that with

```
gcc main.c -o program
```

Then you start it with:

```
./program file.txt
```

Comment: An error occurs that says I need to compile with C99 mode, how do I achieve this?

Comment: `gcc -std=c99 main.c -o program` should do it

Comment: What do you mean by "program" btw... is it the program I want to compile in?

Comment: @Fjodor, no "program" is the name of your program. It could also be `gcc -std=c99 main.c -o fjodorsfirstprogram` for instance. A file will be created with that name.

Comment: Okay, but I have another problem then. When I try to compile I get this error: "undefined reference to 'something'. Could there be some linking problem with my header files? And how do I correct them?

Comment: @Fjodor, linking comes later. Undefined reference means you are trying to use something which either does not exist at all or you have not included correctly, as you said. I think you are trying to do too much at once. Create a simple program first and extend it part by part.

Comment: I am just new to compiling and running via the terminal. My program is complete and I can compile it through codeblocks but I need to compile it through the terminal but my headers are missing... You sure you don't know how I am to include them?

Comment: @Fjodor, that is another question. You include them with `-Iandthedirectorywhereincludesare`

Comment: @Fjodor, probably you can see somewhere in CodeBlocks how it calls gcc and its options.

Comment: Right now I am writing it like this: gcc -std=c99 Program.c -o filename, that's when I get the reference problem. But to include my headers I need to give the directory folder or? How?

Comment: `gcc -Iwhereeveryourheadersare -std=c99 Program.c -o filename` @Fjodor

Comment: I've tried... there's just something that ain't working..
gcc -I/home/user/map -std=c99 Program.c -o filename

Comment: @Fjodor, you need to get your ducks in a row. Can you include all the files you try to include? Which function can't you get working? Are you sure it's spelled correctly? What does CodeBlocks do? How does it call gcc? You are aware it calls gcc under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

depending on which Linux OS you're running with (MAC already has this pre installed), just go to the terminal, and change the path to the folder where your program is. then do gcc main.c -(any file name that you want, you can even just name this 'main'). then you can just type main, and it'll run your program for you.